# How do I fix a valuerror in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having trouble returning a list given a model. The model I have:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.establishment

class Available(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    court = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    avail_time = models.DateTimeField('available time')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.court
```

I am trying to run "Available.objects.filter(club="AV Club") but I get "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'AV Club'".  My end goal is to be able to return the list of avail_times given a club.

Any ideas on how to fix?  This is probably a super basic problem, but I'm new to django and have been banging my head on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`club` arg should be either a `Club` instance or its pk (integer in your case). You need this

```
Available.objects.filter(club__establishment="AV Club")
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreign Key relationships are spanned in django by using `__` (double underscores)

so `club` is just a ForeignKey which is an integer, which is why you are getting the `ValueError` so it appears what you want is establishment and DrTyrsa shows an example on how to query for it.

You can span as many foreign key relationships as necessary (be a aware of performance implications)

if club had a FK to country and country had a code field, imagine:

`Available.objects.filter(club__country__code="USA")`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/